# Button Hit State Limits - Android

Tags: android, button, limits

Sorry about the poor title, it will be a little easier to describe what I mean here.

I made a custom button for my Android app that is a circle, but when I export it as a .png the file is a square and the area that the button can be pressed is the full square. How can I make it so that the only area that the button can be pressed is within the circle? Is there a way to define the exact hit area of the button?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you write your own onTouch handler then you can check if position is inside or outside your button. There is afaik no easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ImageButton for that....

Drag and drop an imagebutton to your layout. set the background to #00000000 (transparent) and the source of it to your png file

this way you'll have a circle button.

Comment: So make a transparent background in the button's file and in the XML?